# Why in Python (1<={}) is evaluated True?

Tags: python, dictionary, evaluation

My problem is that I really don't understand why is that, and if you can explain me what's "happening behind" the evaluation I would really appreciate!

Note: also `(True<={})`, `(False<={})`, `(ANY_NUMBER<={})` returns `True`.

Comment: Python 2 tries to give any sequence, regardless of how many types are involved, a stable order when sorted. It does so by sorting types by their type name, but numbers always come before anything else. This choice is arbitrary, an implementation detail. Python 3 does away with heterogenous sequence ordering altogether.

Comment: Since `bool` is a subclass of `int`, they are numbers in this regard.